# How get audio track from video using SimpleExoPlayerView

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

How to get number of track(track list) using `SimpleExoPlayerView`. And how to apply selected **audio to video**. Please checkout the Screenshot below :

[image: Select Audio Track]

Comment: Did you look into sample given by them at https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo

Comment: No, But this code too huge can you please give me peace of code this only.? @PankajKumar

Comment: @akhilbatlawala if you get any thing relevant to this please let me know.